# Eliminating duplicate valued key from a dict

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary,

```
>>> names
{1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2), 3: ('c1', 3), 4: ('c2', 4)}
```

What is the best way to eliminate keys with duplicate entries based on the first entry in the value i.e 1 and 3 are duplicates because of 'c1' and 2 and 4 are duplicates because of 'c2'?

I would like the final output to be something like this

```
>>> uniqueNames
{1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2) }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried!

Comment: How do you determine whether to keep `1` or `3`? There is no inherent order.

Comment: You should use an OrderedDict if the order matters to you. That way only the first occurrence of the value will remain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to how you would eliminate duplicates in a regular list while keeping the list's order.

The only real difference here is that dictionaries have no order, which means that iteration order through `names.items` is arbitrary so you will keep an arbitrary key-value pair with a unique first item for the value-tuple.

```
>>> names = {1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2), 3: ('c1', 3), 4: ('c2', 4)}
>>> 
>>> seen = set()
>>> unique_names = {}
>>> 
>>> for k, (v0, v1) in names.items():
...     if v0 not in seen:
...         unique_names[k] = (v0, v1)
...         seen.add(v0)
... 
>>> unique_names
{1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the cryptic one-liner such questions tend to elicit:

```
unique_names = dict({i[1][0]: i for i in names.items()}.values())
```

If you want to guarantee to keep the smallest key:

```
unique_names = dict({i[1][0]: i for i in sorted(names.items(), reverse=True)}.values())
```

Collects the old items as values to the keys to be uniquified and builds a new dict from the items that remain as values in said dict.

Comment: Ok, that's clever and cool. Would take me a while staring down what's happening, though.

Comment: @timgeb I agree, if in doubt (or at work) I'd always go with your explicit version. But I like how this wraps all those logical steps concisely.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ulist = []      # unique-list
outdict = {}    # dict for output
for i in names.items():         # i will be as: (1, ('c1', 1))
    if i[1][0] not in ulist:
        ulist.append(i[1][0])   # add unique item to unique-list
        outdict[i[0]] = i[1]    # add entry to output dict
print(outdict)
```

Output:

```
{1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this:

```
names = {1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2), 3: ('c1', 3), 4: ('c2', 4)}

values_set = set()
unique_names = {}
for key, value in names.items():
    if value[0] not in values_set:
        values_set.add(value[0])
        unique_names[key] = value

print(unique_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a set of first tuple values and then knowing what values are unique you can pop keys from the dict.

```
>>> temp = {1: ('a', '1'), 2: ('b', '2'), 3: ('a', '3'), 4: ('b', '4')}
>>> uniques = set()
>>> uniquedict = {}
>>> for key, value in temp.iteritems():
...     if value[0] not in uniques:
...         uniques.update(value[0])
...         uniquedict[key]=value
... 
>>> 
>>> uniquedict
{1: ('a', '1'), 2: ('b', '2')}
```

edit: this is for python 2.7, @mrCarnivore answer is for python 3

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group what you want, and only take the first value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2), 3: ('c1', 3), 4: ('c2', 4)}

groups = defaultdict(list)
for num1, (entry, num2) in d.items():
    groups[entry].append((num1, num2))
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'c1': [(1, 1), (3, 3)], 'c2': [(2, 2), (4, 4)]})

result = {v[0][0]:(k, v[0][1]) for k, v in groups.items()}

print(result)
# {1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2)}
```

Or even with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
grouped = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][0]), key = lambda x: x[1][0])]
# [[(1, ('c1', 1)), (3, ('c1', 3))], [(2, ('c2', 2)), (4, ('c2', 4))]]

result = {k: v for (k, v) in [x[0] for x in grouped]}

print(result)
# {1: ('c1', 1), 2: ('c2', 2)}
```